# Bind reactive form values to html after render

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form being created in my .ts file, and then the html controls and form to bind to are held inside an *ngIf block. if the user clicks edit, the form appears and they submit their new values.

Currently, the form is submitting null values. I'm guessing that this is because the form cannot bind to the html when the html is not rendered. How do I fix this for it to bind properly?

.ts snippet

```
    export class DhcpComponent implements OnInit {
        edit = '';

        editEntryForm: FormGroup;

        constructor(private networkService: NetworkService){}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.editEntryForm = new FormGroup({
                'newHostname': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
                'newMac': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
                'newIp': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
            });

            console.log(this.editEntryForm);
        }

        addEditedEntry(entryEdit) {
            console.log(entryEdit);
        }

        editEntry(entry) {
           // change to edit mode on entry
           this.edit = entry.hostname;
        }
    }
```

.html snippet

```
<button
                        type="button"
                        class="btn-default btn"
                        (click)="editEntry(entry)"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
</button>

<form
            class="edit dhcp-item row"
            *ngIf="edit === entry.hostname"
            [formGroup]="editEntryForm"
            (ngSubmit)="addEditedEntry(editEntryForm)"
        >
            <div class="update-col col">
                <button type="submit" class="update-sub btn btn-secondary">
                    Update
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value="{{ entry.hostname }}"
                    class="form-control"
                    formControlName="newHostname"
                >
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value="{{ entry.mac }}"
                    class="form-control"
                    formControlName="newMac"
                >
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value="{{ entry.ip }}"
                    class="form-control"
                    formControlName="newIp"
                >
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by removing the curly brace interpolation to the value parameter of the input tag:

delete: `value="{{ entry.hostname }}"` etc

To add values dynamically use set value on each edit button click:

```
editEntry(entry) {
        // change to edit mode on entry
        this.edit = entry.hostname;
        this.editEntryForm.setValue({
            'newHostname': entry.hostname,
            'newMac': entry.mac,
            'newIp': entry.ip
        });
}
```

interpolation caused the values to be null since angular is trying to grab the value of the last loop entry each time (thanks to @sancelot for pointing that out).

Answer (score 0):

bind the hidden property instead of using ngIf

```
[hidden]="!showIt"
```

Comment: That seemed promising. but my form values are sill logging as null. this is confusing. Is there an issue with having the same formgroup and form bindings created for each list item that is edited? would it be better to just submit these values with a click function and an element ref?

I guess what i'm getting at: is this possible?

Comment: you used hidden in a div ? and removed ngIf. can you put a code snippet.?

Comment: <form
                class="edit dhcp-item row"
                [hidden]="edit !== entry.hostname"
                [formGroup]="editEntryForm"
                (ngSubmit)="addEditedEntry(editEntryForm)"
            >

and the form was logged to the console from the reactive form submit as: 'null null null' for all 3 values. and I did have text in the inputs

Comment: hidden must be in a div element ; <div  [hidden]="edit !==entry.hostname"><form ....> </div>

Comment: does your form work in normal context ?I mean visible without button activation

Comment: <div [hidden]="edit !== entry.hostname">
                <form
                    class="edit dhcp-item row"
                    [formGroup]="editEntryForm"
                    (ngSubmit)="addEditedEntry(editEntryForm)"
                >

but i'm still getting null values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151443/discussion-between-fussinhussin-and-sancelot).